# Are both the phrases same in meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage, phrases

> **On a continuing basis vs On a regular basis**

I know "On a regular basis mean" = regularly

Then what does "continuing basis" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, continuing means you keep doing something without stopping,  regular is slightly different in a sense that it means you do something hut with time intervals in between it.